# Error "Invalid uncompressed glob" while uploading app-release.aab

Tags: android, google-play

Upload app-release.aab gives this error:

An error occurred while running bundletool build-apks on your uploaded App Bundle. Ensure that your App Bundle is valid by running bundletool build-apks locally and try again. Learn more. Error: Invalid uncompressed glob: '**['.[uU] .....

I get stuck on this "Invalid uncompressed glob" , any hint will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In the case it happens to someone else ...
Don't know how this line in gradle get some char escaped:

the original
noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', '.bundle', '.unityexp'] + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
became

```
 noCompress = [\'.unity3d\', \'.ress\', ....
```

it still build , generate the signed release, but once uploaded raise that error

Comment: I ran into the same error today. Did you find a solution?

Comment: yes .. as said it was the ' char on no compress list strings

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem.
Originally my configuration was:

'['.ress', '.resource', '.obb'] + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')'

Modified to:
'**/*.ress, **/*.resource, **/*.obb, unityStreamingAssets/**'
and it will work.